# Jersey 2.22.2 with wildfly 9.0.2Final Authentication filter deployment error

Tags: java, wildfly, jersey-2.0, wildfly-9, hk2

So I created a custom AuthenticationFilter for a Jersey Rest service. Locally it deploys and works as intended but when deployed to our actual test server I get the below error when starting Wildfly server.

```
Caused by: A MultiException has 3 exceptions.  They are:
1. java.lang.IllegalStateException: A descriptor SystemDescriptor(  implementation=org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.process.ServerProcess>ingBinder$UriRoutingContextFactory
    contracts={org.glassfish.jersey.server.ExtendedUriInfo,javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo,javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceInfo}
    scope=org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped
    qualifiers={}
    descriptorType=PROVIDE_METHOD
    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
    metadata=
    rank=0
    loader=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder$2@19fb4349
    proxiable=true
    proxyForSameScope=false
    analysisName=null
    id=16
    locatorId=5
    identityHashCode=481594768
    reified=true) requires a proxy, but the proxyable library is not on the classpath
2. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of com.lanyon.rest.service.filters.AuthenticationFilter errors were found
3. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on com.lanyon.rest.service.filters.AuthenticationFilter
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A descriptor SystemDescriptor(
    implementation=org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.process.ServerProcess>ingBinder$UriRoutingContextFactory
    contracts={org.glassfish.jersey.server.ExtendedUriInfo,javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo,javax.ws.rs.container.ResourceInfo}
    scope=org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped
    qualifiers={}
    descriptorType=PROVIDE_METHOD
    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
    metadata=
    rank=0
    loader=org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder$2@19fb4349
    proxiable=true
    proxyForSameScope=false
    analysisName=null
    id=16
    locatorId=5
    identityHashCode=481594768
    reified=true) requires a proxy, but the proxyable library is not on the classpath"}}}}
```

Here is the Auth filter:

```
@Provider
public class AuthenticationFilter implements javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter {

    private static final String AUTHORIZATION_PROPERTY = "Authorization";
    private static final String AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME = "Basic";
    private static final Response ACCESS_DENIED = Response.status(Response.Status.UNAUTHORIZED)
            .entity("Access Denied").build();
    private static final Response ACCESS_FORBIDDEN = Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN)
            .entity("Forbidden").build();

    private static final String WS_CREDENTIALS_KEY = "DEMAND_WEBSERVICE_CREDENTIALS";
    private static final String DEFAULT_DAO_BEAN_NAME = "exchangeDefaultsDAO";

    @Context
    private ResourceInfo resourceInfo;

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        Method method = getResourceMethod();
        if (isAnnotationPresent(method, PermitAll.class)) {
            return;
        }

        if (isAnnotationPresent(method, DenyAll.class)) {
            requestContext.abortWith(ACCESS_FORBIDDEN);
            return;
        }

        final List<String> authorization = getAuthorizationHeaders(requestContext);

        if (authorization == null || authorization.isEmpty()) {
            requestContext.abortWith(ACCESS_DENIED);
            return;
        }

        String encodedUserPassword = authorization.get(0).replaceFirst(AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME + " ", "");
        final String authToken = new String(encodedUserPassword.getBytes());

        if (isAnnotationPresent(method, RolesAllowed.class)) {
            RolesAllowed rolesAnnotation = getRolesAllowedAnnotation(method);
            Set<String> rolesSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(rolesAnnotation.value()));

            if (!isUserAllowed(authToken, rolesSet)) {
                requestContext.abortWith(ACCESS_DENIED);
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean isUserAllowed(final String authToken, final Set<String> rolesSet) {
        String[] webServiceCredentials = getWebServiceCredentials();
        if (webServiceCredentials.length != 2) {
            return false;
        }
        return authToken.equals(webServiceCredentials[0]) && rolesSet.contains(webServiceCredentials[1]);
    }

    private String[] getWebServiceCredentials() {
        return getExchangeDefaultsBean().getDefault(WS_CREDENTIALS_KEY).split("\\|");
    }

    private Method getResourceMethod() {
        return resourceInfo.getResourceMethod();
    }

    private List<String> getAuthorizationHeaders(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
        final MultivaluedMap<String, String> headers = requestContext.getHeaders();
        final List<String> authorization = headers.get(AUTHORIZATION_PROPERTY);

        return authorization;
    }

    private boolean isAnnotationPresent(Method method, Class<? extends Annotation> annotation) {
        return method.isAnnotationPresent(annotation);
    }

    private RolesAllowed getRolesAllowedAnnotation(Method method) {
        return method.getAnnotation(RolesAllowed.class);
    }

    private ExchangeDefaultsDAO getExchangeDefaultsBean() {
        return (ExchangeDefaultsDAO)ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean(DEFAULT_DAO_BEAN_NAME);
    }
}
```

Then the Jersey Application:

```
public class JerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyApplication() {
        register(AuthenticationFilter.class);
        register(TestAPIService.class);
    }
}
```

Finally the Rest service:

```
@Path("/somepathname")
public class TestAPIService {
    @RolesAllowed("API_ADMIN")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response getRejectReasons() {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("Working as expected!").build();
    }
}
```

I have added javaassist to my classpath but that did nothing. Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: javassist is already pulled in by Jersey, that's why it works fine in your development environment. For some reason, maybe it's either not getting deployed to the server, or something on Wildfly is blocking it from loading.

Comment: So I added javaassist to the pom of the web module but that didnt make a difference, could wildfly be using it's own javaassist that is conflicting with the one from Jersey? Or should I exclude javaassist from Jersey and see what happens?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, but I have no idea how to find out.

Comment: I'm not sure how Wildfly handles class-loading.  However it's pulling in the hk2 libraries needs to also have the javassist in there